# Downgrading an Angular component with Router as a dependency

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am trying to make a hybrid application. I downgraded an Angular (Angular 6.0.0) component that uses angular Router

```
constructor(private router: Router) { }
```

I also added Router and RouterModule as a provider in the module

```
  providers:[
      { provide: 'Router', useClass: Router },
      RouterModule
  ]
```

However, I am getting the following error when opening the angularjs page

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Router: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

How do I resolve this? Is there anything else I need to add? Or did I provide RouterModule via an incorrect way?

Comment: What's the point of downgrading angular to version 6 and not use the latest of whatever the version 6 is at. AFAIK you don't put `RouterModule` in providers but import the module...

Comment: change 'Router' to Router without the quotation marks you do not want to provide a string but a class